# Pass a list to a class python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this simple class:

```
class revs:
    def __init__(self, rev, us, accs = []):
        self.rev = rev
        self.us = us
        self.accs = accs
```

And i have this piece of code to asign values to the list and is inside of a loop

```
rev, usu = cada_l.split("|")
acct = each_l[:2].strip()
list_acct.append(acct)
```

and last, i create a dict, to manage a list of revs like this:

```
drevs = {}
cada = revs(rev, us, list_acct)
drevs[cada.rev] = cada
```

And it Works correctly with rev and us, but with list_acct is ever updating all the instances:

```
drevs['1'].rev
'1'
drevs['2'].rev
'2'
drevs['1'].us
'user1'
drevs['2'].us
'user2'
drevs['1'].accs
'["Doc1","Doc2"]'
drevs['2'].accs
'["Doc1","Doc2"]'
```

And if i change list_acct.clear(), the values in all the instances is clear, I'm still fairly new to Python and this confuses me.

Thanks

Comment: Default `accs` to `None`, and check for it within `__init__`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like it's happening because you're passing the same list to every object. As a result, all the objects maintain references to the same list, and since `list` is mutable, it appears to change "all" of them at once.

To fix this, either pass in a *new* empty list each time you create a `revs` object, or else clone the list you're passing in:

```
cada = revs(rev, us, list_acct[:])
```

**Note that if `list_acct` contains mutable objects, you could still get into the same problem again, but one level deeper!**

If you're not passing lists to the `revs` objects when you create them at all (I can't tell, since you're not showing your full code!), then you have the same problem, but for a different reason: in Python, default arguments are all evaluated once, at the time of the function definition. Therefore, you can get this behavior:

```
r1 = revs(1, 1)
r2 = revs(2, 2)
r1.accs.append("Hi!")
print(r1.accs) # prints ['Hi!']
print(r2.accs) # prints ['Hi!']
```

Because the default argument for the `revs` constructor is always pointing to the same list. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for an explanation as to why, but to get around it, just use `None` as your default instead of `[]`.

```
class revs:
    def __init__(self, rev, us, accs=None):
        self.rev = rev
        self.us = us
        if accs is None:
            accs = []
        self.accs = accs
```